# $ symbol is stripped from command line

Tags: shell, escaping

I'm using the command line:

```
$ruby run.rb add $10000
```

and the second argument `$10000` appears to be passed to ruby as `0000`. How do I prevent `$1` from being stripped?

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape it on the shell. The shell interprets `$1` as a variable. This should work:

```
$ ruby run.rb add \$1000
```

You could also single-quote the string:

```
$ ruby run.rb add '$1000'
```